# Giving specific values but returns wrong pointer

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement, struct

I have a struct which contains different grade words.
For example, if you get an A grade, the words to describe you are "Brilliant", "Fantastic". If you get a B grade, the words to describe you are "Good", "Not bad". These words are stored as structs.

However, I need to create a function (`grade_pnter_finder`), where I parse in the grade, and if its the head or tail of that grade, and it returns me that grade word's struct. However, it keeps returning me the same pointer over regardless of the grade. If I give it the Grade A for tail, it returns me pointer 100. If I give it the grade B for tail, it returns me pointer 100.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct grade {
    struct grade_word *A_head;
    struct grade_word *A_tail;

    struct grade_word *B_head;
    struct grade_word *B_tail;

    struct grade_word *C_head;
    struct grade_word *C_tail;

    struct grade_word *D_head;
    struct grade_word *D_tail;

    struct grade_word *E_head;
    struct grade_word *E_tail;

};

struct grade_word {
    char *word;
    int word_len;
    struct grade_word *next;
    struct grade_word *prev;
};

struct grade *create_grade() {

    struct grade *new_grade = malloc(sizeof(struct grade));

    // Check grade was allocated correctly
    if (new_grade == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not allocate memory for grade\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Initialise all variables
    new_grade->A_head = NULL;
    new_grade->A_tail = NULL;
    new_grade->B_head = NULL;
    new_grade->B_tail = NULL;
    new_grade->B_head = NULL;
    new_grade->C_tail = NULL;
    new_grade->C_head = NULL;
    new_grade->C_tail = NULL;
    new_grade->D_head = NULL;
    new_grade->D_tail = NULL;
    new_grade->E_head = NULL;
    new_grade->E_tail = NULL;

    return new_grade;
}

struct grade_word *grade_pnter_finder(struct grade *grade_data, char grade,
                                      char h_or_t) {

    struct grade_word *target = NULL;
    if (grade == 'A') {
        if (h_or_t == 'H') {
            target = grade_data->A_head;
        } else {
            target = grade_data->A_tail;
        }
    } else if (grade == 'B') {
        if (h_or_t == 'H') {
            target = grade_data->B_head;
        } else {
            target = grade_data->B_tail;
        }
    } else if (grade == 'C') {
        if (h_or_t == 'H') {
            target = grade_data->C_head;
        } else {
            target = grade_data->C_tail;
        }
    } else if (grade == 'D') {
        if (h_or_t == 'H') {
            target = grade_data->D_head;
        } else {
            target = grade_data->D_tail;
        }
    } else {
        if (h_or_t == 'H') {
            target = grade_data->E_head;
        } else {
            target = grade_data->E_tail;
        }
    }

    if (h_or_t == 'H') printf("Grade %c's Head pointer is at: %p\n", grade, &target);
    else printf("Grade %c's Tail pointer is at: %p\n", grade, &target);
    return target;
}

int main(void) {

    struct grade *new_grade = create_grade();
    struct grade_word *pnter;
    pnter = grade_pnter_finder(new_grade, 'A', 'H');
    pnter = grade_pnter_finder(new_grade, 'A', 'T');
    pnter = grade_pnter_finder(new_grade, 'B', 'H');
    pnter = grade_pnter_finder(new_grade, 'B', 'T');
    pnter = grade_pnter_finder(new_grade, 'C', 'H');
    pnter = grade_pnter_finder(new_grade, 'C', 'T');
    pnter = grade_pnter_finder(new_grade, 'D', 'H');
    pnter = grade_pnter_finder(new_grade, 'D', 'T');
    pnter = grade_pnter_finder(new_grade, 'E', 'H');
    pnter = grade_pnter_finder(new_grade, 'E', 'T');

    printf("Stop compiler complaining for unused variable = %p\n", &pnter);


}
```

---

Output:

```
Grade A's Head pointer is at: 0028FEFC
Grade A's Tail pointer is at: 0028FEFC

Grade B's Head pointer is at: 0028FEFC
Grade B's Tail pointer is at: 0028FEFC

Grade C's Head pointer is at: 0028FEFC
Grade C's Tail pointer is at: 0028FEFC

Grade D's Head pointer is at: 0028FEFC
Grade D's Tail pointer is at: 0028FEFC

Grade E's Head pointer is at: 0028FEFC
Grade E's Tail pointer is at: 0028FEFC

Stop compiler complaining for unused variable = 0028FF28
```

As you can see,  It all points to the same place. Shouldn't it point in difference places?

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files your code is actually including?

Comment: `new` is a reserved word in C++ and several persons are using a C++ compiler.  Strongly suggest replacing `new` with a non-reserved word.

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `printf("A pointer %p\n", &grade_data->A_tail);`  This contains a syntax error.  Suggest using: `printf("A pointer %p\n", (void *)&grade_data->A_tail);

Comment: Why all to calls to `printf()` when looking at the `tail` but never when looking at the `head`?

Comment: @user3629249 -- I don't see a syntax error there, but it is undefined behavior to print an address without first casting to `void *`. Also, `new` is not reserved in C. It may not be the _best_ practice to use it in C, but then it is a _worse_ practice to compile C code with a C++ compiler.

Comment: @user3629249 I've updated by code. Should compile now. Also this is C, not c++. And the pointer's print out properly (This is how I was taught to print out pointers)

Comment: @DavidBowling I've uploaded the code so I don't use `new`. I use `new_grade`

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the value printed by:

```
if (h_or_t == 'H') printf("Grade %c's Head pointer is at: %p\n", grade, &target);
else printf("Grade %c's Tail pointer is at: %p\n", grade, &target);
```

You should change `&target` to `target`. You want to print the value of the local variable, not the location where it is stored in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code is showing the same address for each address printed because it is printing the value of `&target` each time. But, `target` itself is a pointer to a `grade_word` structure, with its own address. It is the address of `target` that is being printed, not the value *held* by `target`, i.e., the address that `target` points to.

Note that printing addresses as this code does, e.g. with `printf("Grade %c's Tail pointer is at: %p\n", grade, &target);`, causes undefined behavior according to the C Standard, which says of the `%p` conversion specifier that ["the argument shall be a pointer to void."](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8)

Instead, this code should be:

```
printf("Grade %c's Tail pointer is at: %p\n", grade, (void *) target);
```

Even after fixing the above two issues, note that the pointers in the newly created `grade_word` structure have all been initialized to `NULL`, but none have them have been set to point anywhere meaningful.